# Problems compiling RenderScript

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-view

I've followed this tutorial:

https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-blur-images-efficiently-with-androids-renderscript/

However, wherever the `rs` variable is mentioned, I get the following error:

```
Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'android.support.v8.renderscript.RenderScript', required: 'android.renderscript.RenderScript'
```

This is my `build.gradle`:

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    renderscriptTargetApi 19
    renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do your imports look for the BlurBuilder.java? All the renderscript ones should be "android.support.v8.renderscript".

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing:

```
import android.renderscript.Allocation;
import android.renderscript.Element;
import android.renderscript.RenderScript;
import android.renderscript.ScriptIntrinsicBlur;
```

Replaces those lines only by:

```
android.support.v8.renderscript.*
```

Good luck! (:

Comment: I'm so glad the tools fixed most of these over the last few months. Makes it worthwhile. to know this stuff rather than a giant set of headaches.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are mixing and matching "android.renderscript" and "android.support.v8.renderscript", as mentioned by #user5195185.

Also, try use Build-Tools 23.0.3 which includes several fixes for the support lib:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        renderscriptTargetApi 19
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
    }
}
```